# is it possible to deploy .NET applications to AWS Beanstalk using Git?

Tags: asp.net, git, deployment, amazon-web-services

I need to deploy a .NET application to AWS Beanstalk.  I use a Mac and don't have Visual Studio.  Preferably the developer should not have to download and configure AWS deployment or extensions to VS.NET.

In my perfect world I would Git Push the .NET solution and it would compile and run the application.  Is such a thing possible and practiced?

Comment: Where is your git repo stored? Are you using continuous integration tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to git push .NET source code to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. You need to push compiled applications that are packaged into a Webdeploy archive.

Comment: I saw this in PHP - I take it you know about it and it doesn't work for .NET, correct? http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/03/20/php-and-git-deployment-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Is this still the case in 2015?